# In android app development, can I set a line in String resource justified as centre

Tags: android, string

I have four lines in my string.

```
<string name="s1">  This is Line1 \n
  This is Line2 \n
  Heading for Line4 \n 
  This is Line4  </string>
```

This String "s1" is used in a textview. I want 3rd line to be aligned as center, rest three as left aligned within that textview. 
I cannot set center attribute in texview itself, as it will align all 4 lines. Cannot draw 4 different textviews as its looking ugly, because of background of textview. Is it possible. If not any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do one thing for this....android supports many Html tags in string.

```
<string name="s1">  This is Line1 \n
  This is Line2 \n
  <center>Heading for Line4</center>\n 
  This is Line4  </string>
```

and you can set that value in Textview like this...

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.s1)));
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But your suggestion is not working, My further analysis is suggesting that this thing might not be possible. Looks like we can use only <b>, <i> and <u>. centre is not supported.